# `rescue in retrieve_store_class': Could not find cache store adapter for dalli_store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, dalli

Used versions below

- rails 5.2.8
- ruby 2.3.1
- dalli 3.0.4

I receive the following error:

```
cache.rb:110:in `rescue in retrieve_store_class': Could not find cache store adapter for dalli_store (cannot load such file -- active_support/cache/dalli_store) (RuntimeError)
```

```
def retrieve_store_class(store)
  # require_relative cannot be used here because the class might be
  # provided by another gem, like redis-activesupport for example.
  require "active_support/cache/#{store}"
rescue LoadError => e
  raise "Could not find cache store adapter for #{store} (#{e})"
else
  ActiveSupport::Cache.const_get(store.to_s.camelize)
end
```

Below code i have changed but same error coming.

```
def retrieve_store_class(store)
  # require_relative cannot be used here because the class might be
  # provided by another gem, like redis-activesupport for example.
  begin #added begin statement after getting error
    require "active_support/cache/#{store}"
  rescue LoadError => e
    raise "Could not find cache store adapter for #{store} (#{e})"
  else
    ActiveSupport::Cache.const_get(store.to_s.camelize)
  end
end
```

Comment: [Files in Rails 5.2.8 `active_support/cache` directory](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/v5.2.8/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache), `LoadError` is expected behavior when attempting to require a non-existent file. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have set `config.cache_store = :dalli_store`. This active support cache store implementation was provided by the dalli gem itself before dalli 3.0.

Since dalli 2.7.11, the cache store [was deprecated](https://github.com/petergoldstein/dalli/commit/f82b9e131fec0b5c3ee341e7c89d7737f67c20a7) however in favor of Rails' own mem_cache_store client which uses dalli internally.

With the release of dalli 3.0.0, the `dalli_store` (and all other rails specific code) was entirely [removed from dalli](https://github.com/petergoldstein/dalli/commit/ebeb8f54e668ea89bcac216b31208630a7a4c735).

To continue using memcache as your cache store, you should thus use Rails' own `mem_cache_store`.

See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-memcachestore and https://github.com/petergoldstein/dalli/wiki/Using-Dalli-with-Rails for details about how to use dalli with Rails.